# Invalid C if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement

I am teaching myself C and I seem to be getting incorrect output when running the program. I always get 'They are equal', even if they are not, also, the return value seems to only print the first word of whatever is inputted, how can I fix this?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
char var[0];
char var2[0];
int main(void) {
    printf("Enter Var 1=> ");
    scanf("%s", &var);
    printf(var);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter Var 2=> ");
    scanf("%s", &var2);
    printf(var2);
    printf("\n");
    if (var == var2)
        printf("They are equal");
    else
        printf("They Are not equal");
}
```

Comment: `strcmp` is better suited here... `#include<string.h> ...... if(strcmp(var, var2) == 0) { ... }`

Comment: Your `var` and `var2` buffers are zero-length arrays (`[0]`), so your use of `scanf` is writing to unallocated memory and you're encountering undefined behavior.

Comment: `char var[0];
char var2[0];` --> `char var[32];char var2[32];`...`scanf("%31s", var);`... . Also `printf(var);printf("\n");` --> `printf("%s\n", var);` or `puts(var);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `var` and `var2` buffers are zero-length arrays (`[0]`), so your use of `scanf` is writing to unallocated memory and you're encountering undefined behavior.

Allocate a sufficiently sized buffer, preferably on the stack because you should avoid global variables and use a `scanf` format-string with a length restriction: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx

If you're outputting a string without a format-specifier, use `puts` instead of `printf`.

```
int main(void) {

    char var1[100] = {0}; // 100 characters should be sufficient
    char var2[100] = {0};
    puts( "Enter Var 1=> " );
    scanf( "%99s", &var1 ); // restricted to 99 characters, +1 for the null terminator equals 100
    printf( "%s\n", var1 ); 

    puts( "Enter Var 2=> " );
    scanf( "%99s", &var2 );
    printf( "%s\n", var2 );

    if( strcmp( var1, var2 ) == 0 ) { // use strcmp to compare strings, not the `==` operator because C does not have operator overloading
        puts("They are equal");
    }
    else {
        puts("They are not equal");
    }
}
```